# Should I compress images captured by a webcam when sending through network

Tags: c#, image-processing

Recently, I finished my conference application. People can talk and watch to each other. Therefore I capture images (IntPtr of buffer converted to JPEG) from the webcam (DirectShow library). Right now I do not have any problems, since the program was used in a LAN only. But I'm planning to implement a internet version of it.

So my question is: Should I use something else than JPEG? Should I compare image x and image x+1 and only send differences? Should I use Motion-JPEG? (Sorry, I do not know anything about motion-jpeg, but it sounds relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the right track with recognizing that images change little from frame to frame, and that sending a sequence of jpegs is not the way to go. I believe mjpeg sends a sequence of jpegs, and is a poor choice. I do not use c#, but i believe that ffmpeg (a video compression library) makes a c# wrapper.

Comment: I know ffmpeg, but can you be more specific in what functionality I should use from it?

Comment: It has been a while since i used it (and i was using C), but the library had  a function that would accept image buffers and produce  outgoing compressed frames. You feed it image buffers and send the frames on their way. They have some nice example code: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ffmpeg.org%2Fdoxygen%2Ftrunk%2Fencoding_8c-source.html&ei=fK8bT82tO6Pw0gHD_MC1Cw&usg=AFQjCNGff__Sgpr9D36OwyKzfpx-6WW74A&sig2=DyzhGYP51RdHVgVSG0T26A

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg is extremely fast, but is not really well documented and is pure ANSI-C. I think that a better approach in your case is, as you already thought, to compress the difference between image *x* and image *x-1*, this should be enough to provide a significant bandwidth saving.
You should also include a method to compress the whole frame every once in a while, or compress the whole image when the difference with the previous one is above a certain threshold